# How to implement inheritance in node.js modules?

Tags: node.js

I am in process of writing nodejs app. It is based on expressjs. I am confused on doing inheritance in nodejs modules. What i am trying to do is create a model base class, let's say my_model.js.

```
module.exports = function my_model(){
  my_model.fromID = function(){
    //do query here
  }
}
```

Now i want to use those methods in my_model in my other model class. let's say user_model.js
How do i inherit my_model in user_model?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With ES6 the usage of [util.inherits()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) is discouraged in favor of ES6 **class** and **extends**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyStream extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  write(data) {
    this.emit('data', data);
  }
}

const stream = new MyStream();

stream.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`Received data: "${data}"`);
});
stream.write('With ES6');
```

Answer (score 45):

in base_model:

```
function BaseModel() { /* ... */ }

BaseModel.prototype.fromID = function () { /* ... */ };

module.exports = BaseModel;
```

in user_model:

```
var BaseModel = require('relative/or/absolute/path/to/base_model');

function UserModel() {
    UserModel.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

UserModel.super_ = BaseModel;

UserModel.prototype = Object.create(BaseModel.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: UserModel,
        enumerable: false
    }
});

UserModel.prototype.yourFunction = function () { /* ... */ };

module.exports = UserModel;
```

---

Instead of using `Object.create()` directly, you can also use [util.inherits](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor), so your `user_model` becomes:

```
var BaseModel = require('relative/or/absolute/path/to/base_model'),
    util = require('util');

function UserModel() {
    BaseModel.apply(this, arguments);
}

util.inherits(UserModel, BaseModel);

UserModel.prototype.yourFunction = function () { /* ... */ };

module.exports = UserModel;
```

Comment: Can we use utils.inherits in this?

Comment: @askkirati Yes, see the updated answer. `util.inherits` does something very similar to what I've done, it's just my preference to use `Object.create()` directly.

Comment: Hello, how should i access fromID from where i have loaded the UserModel modeule? if i do 
`var user_model = require('./UserModel');`

then doing 
`user_model.fromID();`
 gives undefined user_model to me

Comment: you should do `var userModel = new require('./UserModel');`

Comment: I did this var userModel = new (require('./UserModel'))(params); I needed to pass paramater aswell. this is correct right. it worked

Comment: what is the point of this line? `UserModel.super_.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: @chovy [Delegating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) the construction to the superclass

Comment: public methods are not exposed. What's the point of inheritance if you have to manually define them each time?

Comment: @OliverDixon all properties and methods are exposed here. What do you mean really?

Answer (score 9):

Using `utility.inherits` can also help you decouple the `child` from the `parent`.

Instead of calling the `parent` explicitly, you can use `super_` to call the parent.

```js
var BaseModel = require('relative/or/absolute/path/to/base_model'),
util = require('util');

function UserModel() {
   this.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

util.inherits(UserModel, BaseModel);
```

`utility.inherits` source:

```
var inherits = function (ctor, superCtor) {
ctor.super_ = superCtor;
ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: ctor,
        enumerable: false
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Please, note, that if you use util.inherits you should use UserModel.super_.apply(this, arguments); instead of this.super_.apply(this, arguments);

Answer (score 0):

New to NodeJS dev, and I came here looking for a similar answer.  Based on the accepted answer, I think a possible alternative is to simply not do it.  That code looks painful.  Maybe there are better ways to do it now, but sometimes in software the answer is to think differently.

The JS ecosystem seems to be predicated on composition paradigms, rather than inheritance.  So instead of looking to have `user.js` inherit from `base`, it would be more clean to simply import the functionality you need to support the code-reuse.  Or, move to dotnet core.  :)