# how to extend nodjs prototype module export

Tags: javascript, node.js

I followed this question [How to implement inheritance in node.js modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213495/how-to-implement-inheritance-in-node-js-modules) but it didn't work for me.

```
// usermgmt.js
function Usermgmt() {
};

module.exports = Usermgmt;
```

```
// authentication.js
var Usermgmt = require('./usermgmt');

function Authentication()  {
    Authentication.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}
Authentication.super_ = Usermgmt;

Authentication.prototype = Object.create(Usermgmt.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: Authentication,
        enumerable: false
    }
});

Authentication.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log("test");
};

module.exports = Authentication;
```

```
// index.js
var auth = new require('../modules/authentication');
auth.test();
```

i tryed it also with class but it didn't work. [nodejs version 12 call method in another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61376443/nodejs-version-12-call-method-in-another-method)
I get the error TypeError: auth.test is not a function

Comment: `new require(…)` constructs a new `require` instance! You want `const Auth = require(…)`, and then do `new Auth()`. Or `new (require(…))`.

Comment: thanks 

var auth = new (require('../modules/authentication'));
auth.test(); worked now